# Unable to Process Template Language Expression for Microsoft Forms Integration with Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Trying to understand why this does not work. I am pulling out the information from the Microsoft Forms, then parsing it and handing over to the HTTP request.

Error that I am getting:

```
Unable to process template language expressions in action 
'Get_the_AAD_information_about_the_user' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 
'The template language expression 'parameters('$connections')
['webcontents']['connectionId']' cannot be evaluated because property 
'webcontents' doesn't exist, available properties are 'microsoftforms, 
office365'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions for usage details.'.
```

This is my flow. I am getting the responses from the Microsoft Forms.

[image]

If the email accept is true, then I am getting out the user information from the AAD with HTTP request to Microsoft Graph.

[image]

Also, for the approval part, I am getting approve or reject for the Condition here:

[image]

This is the Parse JSON it's generating.

[image]

And this is where I am using the email from that Parse JSON added to the graph request.

[image]

So far I have tested and seems that this is the issue. Could be that the Accept or Reject values cannot be written as string in the field. How could I define it as an expression instead?

[image]

Comment: You need to show us the json that your expression is evaluating.

Comment: Added additional information. Now it's "r00dd..." as I did some changes, but still the email is not added from the Parse JSON. Graph request should have an email so that I can pull the information about the user from AAD.

Comment: why UserEmailAddress looks like "r00dd"? Try to do the same operation(AAD information) via postman once

Comment: Email is not "r00dd...", it's a variable that contains an email in previous steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I have got the expected result in the following way-*

**Workflow:**

[image]

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Does not work for me. Sorry. Could be because of the approval email data or something. Can't figure out myself.

Comment: Can you check if the graph API is working without conditional action?

Comment: Added the HTTP GET to the Graph that pulls out the user data and it works, right before the Codition. But I see that when I define the parsed email from the form, it does not add it to the HTTP connector but calls the request like this instead https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/. So no variable is added after ..users/

Comment: If you have added it correctly from dynamic variable and saved it, then it should add

Comment: So, I just started from scratch. Logic works. I don't use any JSON parsing. I will build this up without any unnecessary parsing and see if this works out at the end. Thanks a lot for all the input! :)